# Best way to insert timestamp in Vim?

Tags: vim, vi

EditPad Lite has a nice feature (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd>) which inserts a time stamp e.g. "2008-09-11 10:34:53" into your code.

What is the best way to get this functionality in Vim?

(I am using Vim 6.1 on a Linux server via SSH. In the current situation a number of us share a login so I don't want to create abbreviations in the home directory if there is another built-in way to get a timestamp.)

Comment: `!!date +\%Y\%m\%d_\%H\%M` in NORMAL mode

Answer (score 102, accepted):

http://kenno.wordpress.com/2006/08/03/vim-tip-insert-time-stamp/

Tried it out, it works on my mac:

```
:r! date
```

produces:

```
Thu Sep 11 10:47:30 CEST 2008
```

This:

```
:r! date "+\%Y-\%m-\%d \%H:\%M:\%S"
```

produces:

```
2008-09-11 10:50:56
```

Comment: Just a minor note, the space doesn't seem to be necessary -- ":r!date" works also.

Comment: @A.B, skimming through this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15394572/escaping-in-vim-when-shelling-out-so-its-not-expanded-to-filename#comment21790587_15403852, it seems you can escape with a backslash. Can you try that for me?

Comment: Totally works. Other ways to write it are `:r!date "+\%F \%T"` or `:r!date +\%F\ \%T`.

Comment: Went to put this in my vimrc... then noticed I already put it there ages ago.   Works great.

Comment: Works like a charm on my fedora 31. Thank you.

Answer (score 133):

To make it work cross-platform, just put the following in your `vimrc`:

```
nmap <F3> i<C-R>=strftime("%Y-%m-%d %a %I:%M %p")<CR><Esc>
imap <F3> <C-R>=strftime("%Y-%m-%d %a %I:%M %p")<CR>
```

Now you can just press F3 any time inside Vi/Vim and you'll get a timestamp like `2016-01-25 Mo 12:44` inserted at the cursor.

For a complete description of the available parameters check the [documentation of the C function strftime()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/strftime/).

Comment: is there a method to do this system wide (in linux)?

Comment: Is there a method to create or save a file with this timestamp as a file name?

Comment: Thanks, since F3 is already used for something else. I defined a custom command in normal mode `:Date` by adding the following to my `~/.vimrc` configuration file: `command! Date put =strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`. It inserts the date on a new line. didn't manage to make a version without newline.

Comment: @PaulRougieux The following is for inserting the date without the new line:
`command! Date :normal a<C-R>=strftime('%Y-%m-%d')<CR>`

Comment: `:put =strftime('%FT%T%z')|:norm kJ` might be a cleaner way to "insert the date at the current cursor position."

Comment: The C strftime doesn't support RFC3339 timezones

Answer (score 24):

Why is everybody using `:r!`? Find a blank line and type `!!date` from command-mode. Save a keystroke!

[n.b. This will pipe the current line into stdin, and then replace the line with the command output; hence the "find a blank line" part.]

Comment: Dam this is cool, what feature is this though? Where can I read more about it?

Comment: I think it's been around since "classic" vi. It's just the command mode key `!` which can be applied in different ways like using a movement command (`!}` pipe paragraph, or `!E` pipe word) or doubled up to apply to the current line (`!!` just like you use `dd` or `>>` to apply to the current line).

Answer (score 9):

:r! date

You can then add format to the date command (man date) if you want the exact same format and add this as a vim alias as well

:r! date +"\%Y-\%m-\%d \%H:\%M:\%S"

That produces the format you showed in your example (date in the shell does not use \%, but just %, vim replaces % by the name of the current file, so you need to escape it).

You can add a map in your .vimrc for it to put the command automatically, for instance, each time you press F3:

```
:map <F3> :r! date +"\%Y-\%m-\%d \%H:\%M:\%S"<cr>
```

(Edited the  from above :) )
(Edit: change text part to code, so that

```
<F3>
```

can be displayed)

Answer (score 9):

As an extension to @Swaroop C H's answer,

```
^R=strftime("%FT%T%z")
```

is a more compact form that will also print the time zone (actually the difference from UTC, in an ISO-8601-compliant form).

If you prefer to use an external tool for some reason,

```
:r !date --rfc-3339=s
```

will give you a full RFC-3339 compliant timestamp; use `ns` instead of `s` for Spock-like precision, and pipe through `tr ' ' T` to use a capital T instead of a space between date and time.

Also you might find it useful to know that

```
:source somefile.vim
```

will read in commands from `somefile.vim`: this way you could set up a custom set of mappings, etc., and then load it when you're using vim on that account.

Comment: strftime() is a function within vim.  You can also use `:put=strftime(""%FT%T%z")`

Comment: On my machine (Windows 7, gvim 8.0.69), the %F and %T specifiers did not work, but %Y-%m-%d and %H:%M:%S did.  (According to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/strftime/, %F and %T came with an updated version of strftime for C99.)  Also, the %z specifier produced a wordy description of the timezone.

Answer (score 6):

From the [Vim Wikia](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Insert_current_date_or_time).

I use this instead of having to move my hand to hit an F key:

```
:iab <expr> tds strftime("%F %b %T")
```

Now in Insert mode it just type tds and as soon as I hit the space bar or return, I get the date and keep typing.

I put the `%b` in there, because I like seeing the month name.  The `%F` gives me something to sort by date.  I might change that to `%Y%m%d` so there are no characters between the units.

Comment: What does ``tds`` stands for?

Comment: tds  stands for TimeDateStamp.

Answer (score 6):

#### Unix,use:

```
!!date
```

#### Windows, use:

```
!!date /t
```

#### More details:see [Insert_current_date_or_time](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Insert_current_date_or_time)

Comment: Oh God. this's the shortest of all of them! what...

Answer (score 4):

For a unix timestamp:

```
:r! date +\%s
```

You can also map this command to a key (for example F12) in VIM if you use it a lot:

Put this in your .vimrc:

```
map  <F12> :r! date +\%s<cr>
```

Answer (score 2):

I wanted a custom command `:Date` (not a key mapping) to insert the date at the current cursor position.

Unfortunately straightforward commands like `r!date` result in a new line.  So finally I came up with the following:

```
command Date execute "normal i<C-R>=strftime('%F %T')<CR><ESC>"
```

which adds the date/time string at the cursor position without adding any new line (change to `normal a` add after the cursor position).

Comment: While this is working, the command looks overly complicated to me and I feel like there should be a nicer way to do this.  If you know one, please let me know :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using vi in an Eterm for reasons and it turns out that strftime() is not available in vi.

Fought long and hard and finally came up with this:

```
map T :r! date +"\%m/\%d/\%Y \%H:\%M" <CR>"kkddo<CR>
```

Result: 02/02/2021 16:45

For some reason, adding the date-time alone resulted in a blank line *above* the date-time and the cursor set *on* the date-time line.

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| date +"[etc]" <CR> | Enters the date-time |
| "kk | Moves up two lines |
| dd | Deletes the line above the date-time |
| o <CR> | Opens a line below the time and adds a carriage return (linefeed) |

**Bonus:**

vi doesn't read ~/.vimrc, it reads ~/.exrc

Also, this is how it looks in vim/.vimrc:

```
map T  "=strftime("%m/%d/%y %H:%M")<CR>po<CR>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another quick way not included by previous answers: type-

!!date