# VIM function to insert timestamp

Tags: vim, function

Someone in a previous question suggested the following for adding timestamps to VIM:

```
nmap <F3> a<C-R>=strftime("%Y-%m-%d %a %I:%M %p")<CR><Esc>
imap <F3> <C-R>=strftime("%Y-%m-%d %a %I:%M %p")<CR>
```

Instead of using F3, I'd like to insert the timestamp by executing a function instead. For example, typing :Now.

Unfortunately, I don't grok VIM scripting. Can someone help?

Comment: This may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56052/best-way-to-insert-timestamp-in-vim

Comment: Yes Daenyth, that's the "previous question" I referred to and doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @Munchin: Then linking to it would have been a good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:Now` is not a function, it is a command. You can create command out of first mapping with the following code:

```
command -nargs=0 -bar Now execute "normal! a\<C-R>=strftime(\"%Y-%m-%d %a %I:%M %p\")\<CR>"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
" if not has 'Last Change' in first 5 lines
fun! InsertChangeLog()
    let l:flag=0
    for i in range(1,5)
        if getline(i) !~ '.*Last Change.*'
            let l:flag = l:flag + 1
        endif
    endfor
    if l:flag >= 5
        normal(1G)
        call append(0, "File: <+Description+>")
        call append(1, "Created: " . strftime("%a %d/%b/%Y hs %H:%M"))
        call append(2, "Last Change: " . strftime("%a %d/%b/%Y hs %H:%M"))
        call append(3, "author: <+digite seu nome+>")
        call append(4, "site: <+your website+>")
        call append(5, "twitter: <+your twitter here+>")
        normal gg
    endif
endfun
" map F4 to insert change log
map <special> <F4> <esc>:call InsertChangeLog()<cr>

" update changefile log
" http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/vim/message/51005
" automaticaly update Last Change whitout change jump list
" see :h keepjumps
fun! LastChange()
    let _s=@/
    let l = line(".")
    let c = col(".")
    if line("$") >= 5
        1,5s/\s*Last Change:\s*\zs.*/\="" . strftime("%Y %b %d %X")/ge
    endif
    let @/=_s
    call cursor(l, c)
endfun
autocmd BufWritePre * keepjumps call LastChange()


" place holders snippets - change map !!!
" File Templates
" --------------
"  <leader>j jumps to the next marker
" iabbr <buffer> for for <+i+> in <+intervalo+>:<cr><tab><+i+>
function! LoadFileTemplate()
    "silent! 0r ~/.vim/templates/%:e.tmpl
    syn match vimTemplateMarker "<+.\++>" containedin=ALL
    hi vimTemplateMarker guifg=#67a42c guibg=#112300 gui=bold
endfunction
function! JumpToNextPlaceholder()
    let old_query = getreg('/')
    echo search("<+.\\++>")
    exec "norm! c/+>/e\<CR>"
    call setreg('/', old_query)
endfunction
autocmd BufNewFile * :call LoadFileTemplate()
nnoremap <leader>j :call JumpToNextPlaceholder()<CR>a
inoremap <leader>j <ESC>:call JumpToNextPlaceholder()<CR>a
```