# vim place timestamp in filename

Tags: vim, timestamp, filenames

I have been trying to insert a timestamp into filenames inside vim.  The best example I found is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56052/best-way-to-insert-timestamp-in-vim/58604#58604).  Although this works with place the timestamp in the file, it does not work in the command line.  Here is what I have in vimrc:

```
nmap <F3> a<C-R>=strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M")<CR><Esc>
imap <F3> <C-R>=strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M")<CR>
```

At the command line I type:

```
:sav i<C-R><F3>.txt
```

Hoping to get:

```
i201102121400.txt
```

Instead, I get:

```
E15: Invalid Expression: <F3>
E15: Invalid Expression: <F3>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Also, I am using both Windows and Linux, so it has to work on both.

Bonus: If I can get it to get UTZ time instead of localtime, that would be fantastic!

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the cmap, not nmap or imap.

add the same line for setting F3 in the cmap, the command line map

```
cmap <F3> <C-R>=strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M")<CR>
```

remove the nmap and imap mappings if you don't really need the timestamp or want to use them inside the edit buffers.

Comment: Thanks! Just one question, is it possible to insert time by typing some word, for example `:w %tstamp%-some.conf` > `20140301-some.conf`?

Comment: Yes, it's possible `cab tstamp <C-R>=strftime("%Y%m%d")<CR>` and abbreviation expands at next symbol, vim is great!