# How do I insert current time into a file using vim

Tags: vim

I'm just logging some work as I do it, each line being an action, I will be trying to do this every few minutes.  Is there a trick way of inserting date/time something like:

```
14 June 2011 15:01:00 Downloaded source code from GIT
```

Would do fine... although thinking about it, inserting the date as I add a new line might be nice too..

Any other shortcuts that anyone else uses when trying to achieve similar would also be welcome.

(Win32, vim6.4)

**EDIT**

Here is what I ended up with: I type: appending 'vlog' then a space, like so

```
that was 30 minutes well spent vlog
```

and my log entry goes:

```
that was 30 minutes well spent 
Jun-14 16:50
```

With me ready to type the next line, thats with With the .vimrc (_vimrc) entry:

```
"use this for file logging 
:iab vlog <cr><c-r>=strftime("%b-%d %H:%M") <cr>
```

Cor! now lets get that 30 minutes back... cheers for the replies!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56052/best-way-to-insert-timestamp-in-vim

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I prefer to set an abbreviation for this like:

```
iab xdate <c-r>=strftime("%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S")<cr>
```

So when I type `"Downloaded source code on xdate"`, vim automatically expands the `"xdate"` to `"14/06/11 hrs:mins:secs"`. Being in insert mode and not having to disrupt my flow of typing to either get into normal mode or press a shortcut is useful at times. Also, you can set it to a shorter combination than `"xdate"` if you so wish.

Comment: Thanks very much, sorry my search skills were lacking there.  So what would I need to add to that so that I when I type xdate it a)adds a new line then b) inserts the date ? (win32)

Comment: @Cups: Just change it to `iab xdate <cr><c-r>=strftime("%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S")<cr>` (I have added a `<cr>` before the `<c-r>` to introduce a carriage return, which creates a new line)

Answer (score 3):

See [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Insert_current_date_or_time)

Press F5 in normal mode or in insert mode to insert the current datestamp:

```
:nnoremap <F5> "=strftime("%c")<CR>P
:inoremap <F5> <C-R>=strftime("%c")<CR>
```

Answer (score -1):

This should help you:
[Insert current date or time](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Insert_current_date_or_time)