# Escaping "%" in Vim when shelling out, so it's not expanded to filename?

Tags: vim

Say I have this vimscript as "/tmp/example.vim":

```
let g:input = "START; % END"
exec("! clear && echo " . shellescape(g:input))
```

If I open that file and run it with `:so %`, the output will be

```
START; /tmp/example.vim END
```

because the "%" is expanded to the buffer name. I want the output to be

```
START; % END
```

I can use the generic `escape()` method to escape percent signs in particular. This works:

```
let g:input = "START; % END"
exec("! clear && echo " . escape(shellescape(g:input), "%"))
```

But is that really the best way? I'm sure there're more characters I should escape. Is there a specific escape function for this purpose? Or a better way to shell out?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For use with the `:!` command, you need to pass the optional `{special}` argument to `shellescape()`:

> When the `{special}` argument is present and it's a non-zero
>   Number or a non-empty String (|non-zero-arg|), then special
>   items such as `!`, `%`, `#` and `<cword>` will be preceded by
>   a backslash.  This backslash will be removed again by the |`:!`|
>   command.

```
:exec("! clear && echo " . shellescape(g:input, 1))
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to properly escape the '%'. So it should be:

```
let g:input = "START; \\% END"
```

Comment: The input in my real script is not fixed. I could use `escape()` to generally escape every "%", but see the end of the question.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do it:

```
let g:input = "START; % END"
echo system("echo " . shellescape(g:input))
```

It should be noted I don't really care about the output; I'll use this with `silent` in a larger script.

Comment: If you're discarding the echoed text anyway, you can use `call`.

Comment: @echristopherson Yeah, that was just to see the output in the example script.