# Insert timestamp on newline in vim

Tags: vim

I would like to make Vim insert a timestamp each time I make a new line. From [Best way to insert timestamp in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56052/best-way-to-insert-timestamp-in-vim) I can see there's a way of inserting a timestamp on keypress:

```
nmap <F3> a<C-R>=strftime("%Y-%m-%d %a %I:%M %p")<CR><Esc>
imap <F3> <C-R>=strftime("%Y-%m-%d %a %I:%M %p")<CR>
```

Likely I could just map <kbd>Enter</kbd> to this, instead of <kbd>F3</kbd>; however, this is a kludge (for instance, I could press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>). Is there a way to trigger an action on newline in Vim?

Answer (score 1):

`<CR>`, `<Enter>`, and `<C-M>` are all synonyms in Vim. Therefore, it's sufficient to define this mapping:

```
:imap <buffer> <CR> <CR><C-R>=strftime("%Y-%m-%d %a %I:%M %p ")<CR>
```

I chose a buffer-local mapping because you probably only want this for certain filetypes. You can define that for certain filetypes by prepending `:autocmd Filetype <filetype> ...`, and put that into your `~/.vimrc`. But that get's unwieldy as you add mappings and other settings for various filetypes. Better put the commands into `~/.vim/ftplugin/<filetype>_mappings.vim`. (This requires that you have `:filetype plugin on`.)

This still won't cover *pasted text*. I doubt you'd really want that (it's better to prepend the timestamps afterwards), but you can look into the (recently added) `TextChanged` event to implement that.