# Linux command line output appended to file with new line

Tags: linux, bash

What is the best way to output the date into a file plus a blank line and have vi ready to go at the new line:

So far i have:

```
date >> myfile && vi myfile
```

But it doesnt do 2 things:

1. Adds the new line
2. Starts editing at the end of the file

Comment: Are you really looking for something more generalized to any command, or specifically for `date`?  Because Vim (maybe Vi too) can read in the date on its own http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56052/best-way-to-insert-timestamp-in-vim

Comment: Maybe as simple as `vi -c ":r! date" myfile` and with `+` to move to the end (in vim):   `vim -c ":r! date" + myfile`

Answer (score 4):

Initial editing position:
`+[num]` starts editing at the specified line number, or EOF if omitted.  Many editors support this, so they can be invoked from `less` at the current view position.

Getting an extra newline:
Either use a custom format for `date` that ends with two newlines, or do:

```
{ date && echo; } >> myfile && vi + myfile
```

Answer (score 1):

```
date >> myfile && vi -c 'normal Go' myfile
```

This is a way.