# vim - insert timestamp in the current line after some words?

Tags: vim

I want insert the timestamp **in the current line without ruin the content in that line.** I've read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56052/best-way-to-insert-timestamp-in-vim). Basically it suggests:1). `!r date` which insert on the next line; 2). `!!date` which clear current line and insert the timestamp.

Comment: Where do you want to insert in the current line, at the cursor?

Comment: @SibiCoder yes, of course

Comment: Then have a mapping that inserts the result of strftime: e.g. `inoremap keybinding <c-r>=strftime('%c')<cr>`

Comment: IOW forget the accepted answer in the other q/a. The answer you were looking for has a higher rank. Unless there is something you haven't understood, your question is a duplicate of the other one.

Comment: @LucHermitte I can't understand the key binding, how can I bind to some other keys? I'm using mac, F3 is a system hotkey

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you have to do is mapping <kbd>**F3**</kbd>:

```
inoremap <special> <F3> <c-r>=strftime('%c')<CR>
```

With this way whenever you press <kbd>**F3**</kbd> button it will insert timestamp at current position during insert-mode.

---

#### Explanation:

```
[i][noremap] [<special>] [<F3>] [<c-r>=strftime('%c')<CR>]
 |   |          |          |      |
 |   |          |          |      |
 |   |          |          |      |---> Whenever you press <F3> button it 
 |   |          |          |      |---> will execute this part
 |   |          |          |      |---> it is like pressing ctrl-r 
 |   |          |          |      |---> then pressing = and typing
 |   |          |          |      |---> strftime('%c') and then 
 |   |          |          |      |---> typing enter (<cr>) for execution
 |   |          |          | 
 |   |          |          |---> The key that you want to map
 |   |          |
 |   |          |----> This argument is for avoiding side effect of 'cpoption'
 |   |
 |   |-----> The  mapping (noremap) is not recursive
 |   |
 |   |-----> It means that it doesn't care about other mappings 
 |   
 |---------> (i) for insert-mode (n) for normal-mode (c) for command-mode ...
```

---

For more see [**:help map.txt**](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html)

Answer (score 4):

```
iab idate <c-r>=strftime("%c")<cr>
```

No need to use any shortcut, just type "idate" or any other word of your choice (iab stands for insert mode abbreviation)

If you have [ultisnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips) plugin you can create a snippet like this:

```
snippet date "use tab to insert date" w
`date +%Y-%m-%d\ %H:%M` ${0}
endsnippet
```

Comment: What does `${0}` do?

Comment: It is a placeholder for the last jump of the snippet, in this particular case the only one.

Answer (score 1):

As SergioAraujo suggested, you can use [ultisnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips) together with [vim-snippets](https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets). Ultisnips is the snippet engine and vim-snippets provides the actual snippets. You can also install the auto-complete [deoplete](https://github.com/Shougo/deoplete.nvim) to complete your snippet.

Back to your question, vim-snippets provides several time or date related snippets, for example `date`, `time`, `datetime`, `diso` etc.. You can find them [here](https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets/blob/master/UltiSnips/all.snippets#L77). After input the snippet keyword, you can press `Tab` to expand the snippet to its full content.

Answer (score 0):

I have a set of mapped keys for inserting timestamps at my cursor's position.

```
"--- datetime stamps
inoremap dts <c-r>=strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")<CR>
inoremap dtz <c-r>=strftime("%F %T%z")<CR>
"--- date stamps
inoremap ymd <c-r>=strftime("%Y%m%d")<CR>
inoremap ymd- <c-r>=strftime("%Y-%m-%d")<CR>
inoremap dny <c-r>=strftime("%d-%b-%Y")<CR>
"--- time stamps
inoremap tz <c-r>=strftime("%T%z")<CR>
inoremap ts <c-r>=strftime("%H%M%S")<CR>
```

... `inoremap` used, as well as `nnoremap` for normal mode.

Your mileage may vary, your formats most definitely *will* vary.